# Spyder throws AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'modules' when importing DBSCAN 3 times

Tags: python, scikit-learn, spyder

I am using Spyder 3.3.2 and scikit-learn Version: 0.20.1. I am running a script that starts importing DBSCAN by:

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
```

The first two times I run the script, it works ok. However,the third time I invariably get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-3-f629b84de3e3>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('/home/mario/Documents/python_machine_learning_projects/test_for_question.py', wdir='/home/mario/Documents/python_machine_learning_projects')

File "/home/mario/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/home/mario/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 100, in execfile
builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

File "/home/mario/Documents/enerchemtek/python_machine_learning_projects/test_for_question.py", line 9, in <module>
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

File "/home/mario/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from .spectral import spectral_clustering, SpectralClustering

File "/home/mario/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/spectral.py", line 15, in <module>
from ..metrics.pairwise import pairwise_kernels

File "/home/mario/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from .ranking import auc

File "/home/mario/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/ranking.py", line 36, in <module>
from ..preprocessing import label_binarize

File "/home/mario/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from ._function_transformer import FunctionTransformer

File "/home/mario/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_function_transformer.py", line 5, in <module>
from ..utils.testing import assert_allclose_dense_sparse

File "/home/mario/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/testing.py", line 54, in <module>
from nose.tools import raises as _nose_raises

File "/home/mario/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from nose.core import collector, main, run, run_exit, runmodule

File "/home/mario/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 11, in <module>
from nose.config import Config, all_config_files

File "/home/mario/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/config.py", line 9, in <module>
from nose.plugins.manager import NoPlugins

File "/home/mario/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/__init__.py", line 185, in <module>
from nose.plugins.manager import *

File "/home/mario/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 418, in <module>
import pkg_resources

File "/home/mario/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
from pkg_resources.extern import six

File "/home/mario/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py", line 44, in load_module
mod = sys.modules[extant]

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'modules'
```

If I run the script in a terminal by doing:

```
python MyScript.py
```

it all works ok, so it must be a problem with Spyder. Also, the error is replicated if I run a script that contains only that line of code.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The traceback tells a story of something going badly wrong inside the `pkg_resources` package. The imported `sys` seems to have been reassigned to `None`. If you did not modify or monkey patch it it's a bug.

Comment: I didn't modify nor patch anything. Is there something I can do?

Comment: Have you tried re-starting / re-installing the spyder?

Comment: Of course, re-starting / re-installing is the first thing I tried.

Comment: If it's a bug, where should I report it?